# Cómo mostrar datepicker sobre el modal, angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Tengo el siguiente modal y dentro de el tengo un campo fecha que debe dezplegar utiizando datepicker

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="modal_header_footer_crear">
                <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
                    <div class="uk-modal-header">
                        <h3 class="uk-modal-title">Crear Solicitud</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form id="form_validation" class="uk-form-stacked">
                        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Producto<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.idproducto" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Proveedor<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.idproveedorsolicitud" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <div class="uk-input-group"> 
                                        <span class="uk-input-group-addon"><i class="uk-input-group-icon uk-icon-calendar"></i></span>
                                        <label for="uk_dp_1">Fecha*</label>
                                        <input class="md-input" type="text" id="uk_dp_1" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" md-input ng-model="item.fecha_solicitud">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Cantidad<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.cantidad" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Estado<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.estado" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Precio<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.precio" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
                            <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <label for="fullname">Total<span class="req">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="item.total" required class="md-input" md-input />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
                        <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-flat uk-modal-close">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="CrearProveedor(item)" class="md-btn md-btn-flat md-btn-flat-primary">Aceptar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

El input de la fecha viene siendo este:

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
                                <div class="parsley-row">
                                    <div class="uk-input-group"> 
                                        <span class="uk-input-group-addon"><i class="uk-input-group-icon uk-icon-calendar"></i></span>
                                        <label for="uk_dp_1">Fecha*</label>
                                        <input class="md-input" type="text" id="uk_dp_1" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" md-input ng-model="item.fecha_solicitud">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Me muestra el datepicker solo que atras del modal, que propiedad puedo utilizar o como aria para que aparezca sobre el modal, correctamente.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en la distribucion de capas con respecto a Z. O lo que es lo mismo si subes el z-index de la clase del datepicker lo traeras mas al frente.

Este es un ejemplo de lo que te pasa.

```css
#modal{
 width: 200px;
 height: 500px; 
background:red;

}

#boxDatepicker{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 position:fixed;
 background:blue; 
 top:0px;

}
```

```html
<div id="modal"></div>

<div id="boxDatepicker"></div>
```

Este seria el ejemplo arreglado

```css
#modal{
 width: 200px;
 height: 500px; 
background:red;

}

#boxDatepicker{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 position:fixed;
 background:blue; 
 top:0px;
z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal"></div>

<div id="boxDatepicker"></div>
```